# spring ldap configuration attributes requirement

Tags: java, spring, authentication, ldap, spring-ldap

my default ldap configuration in application-security.xml is

```
 <ldap-authentication-provider
  server-ref="ldap_server" group-search-filter="member={0}"
  group-search-base="ou=groups" user-search-base="ou=users"
  user-search-filter="uid={0}" group-role-attribute="cn"
  user-dn-pattern="uid={0},ou=users" />
```

Now i have to integrate it with customer ldap server, so i asked for values of following attributes:

```
 group-search-filter
 group-search-base
 user-search-base
 user-search-filter
 group-role-attribute
```

Now customer come back with following details and saying it works for some other third party software:

```
    The current 3rd party setup​:

LDAP Hostname - 10.0.1.213
Port - 636
Secure - Yes
Assume this means SSL
RDN (Bind DN / bind user) - %u@%d
LDAP Domain - ORGANIZATION.local
Bind Password - N/A
User Search Base - ou=users,ou=us,dc=ORGANIZATION,dc=local​
User Search Scope - subtree
```

Now i should ask him that we do need `group` attributes as well ?

As per my understanding these attributes are required to extract group name, group member and username from ldap and customer has just provided with the `user` related attributes

---

We use spring ldap and this is my first time with ldap

Answer (score 0):

If the customer's ldap configuration is a single node without groups, the group attributes can be skipped.

Reference - 19.3.2 :
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ldap.html